# Inheritance Program getting compiler error 58

Tags: java, inheritance

My display method in my sub class does not work. It gives the error: 
**Customer.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
 super.display();
      ^
  symbol: method display()
1 error** The requirements or to print the objects data.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Person
 {
 private String name;
 private String address;
 private String number;

 public Person() //No Argument constructor//
 {
 name= "";
 address= "";
 number= "" ;
 }

 public Person(String num, String nam, String add) //Explicit value constructor//
 {
  number= num;
  name= nam;
  address= add;
 }
  public String getName() //Accessor method//
   {
    return name;
   }

  public void setName(String name )//Mutator method//
   {

    this.name= name;
   }

   public String getAddress()
   {
    return address;
   }
   public void setAddress(String address)
   {
    this.address= address;
   }
   public String getTelephoneNumber()
   {
    return number;
   }
    public void setNumber(String number)
   {
    this.number= number;
   }

    public String toString ()
   {
    return name + "\n" + address + "\n" + number;
   }}
```

The sub class

```
     public class Customer extends Person 
     {

     public Customer(String num, String nam, String add) 
     { 
     super (num, nam, add);

     }

     public boolean checkResponse(char response)
      {
      if (response == "Y")
       {return true;}
        return false;
        }
     }
    public void display()
     {
     super.display();
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here:

```
 public class Customer extends Person {
    String number=""; // you forgot the type declaration
```

Notice that the `number` attribute declared in the superclass won't be visible in this class because it's `private`. One possible solution would be to declare the attributes as protected in class `Person`:

```
protected String number;
```

… But anyway you can't initialize them as you did in class `Customer` (use the constructor for that). And besides it's unnecessary, the superclass already initialized them.

Comment: so I don't need to have String number="";

Comment: but rather one for the boleen ( I am new at this please forgive me for misunderstanding so much)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to not declaring the type of `number`

you are using super (number);

but the Person class does not have a constructor that accepts just one parameter.

So you need to use

```
super( num, nam, add);
```

which will also negate the need for having to declare `number` in the Customer class

So basically to construct the overridenn Person class you need to do

```
public Customer(String num, String nam, String add) 
{ 
  super( num, nam, add);
}

public boolean checkResponse( char response) { 
   if (response == 'Y') { return true; } 
   return false; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me further (sorry very new to this)

Comment: I did this so would I also need to declare the "choice" for the boleen

Comment: Yes `choice` would need to be declared somewhere.

Comment: **public void addChoice(String number, boolean correct)
      {
      choice.add(choice);
      if (correct)
      {
      setAnswer(choiceString);
      }**

Comment: That part of the code is confusing me a bit...I want to implement a if then else statement in order to test it based on a response like: Would you like to continue if response = Y then continue Do you get what I am going for here ?

Comment: This does not seem related to this question.  I suggest you make a new question.

Comment: **public boolean checkResponse( boolean response)
{
char response;

if (response == "Y")
{
return true;
}
else 
{
return false;
}** ok I will edit it but is this a better boolean statment

Comment: The boolean works but my display method gets error Customer.java:17: error: **cannot find symbol
 super.display();
      ^
  symbol: method display()
1 error**

Comment: Hmm, strange, you update your code with my answer, but accept the other answer.  Furthermore you question has morphed so much it no longer makes any sense.  Also your copy for the latest checkReponse is incorrect.  By why would I help you anymore?

Answer (score 0):

One more.

```
 public boolean checkResponse( boolean response)
  {
  char response;
  if (response == "Y")
```

that will not compile. The problems are:

1. You named your char variable the same as the boolean argument
2. You try to compare char response without having initialized it
3. You compare it to a string using ==

Comment: I edited the program, but thank you. My display method is giving me an error.